# Check biometrics appointment availability before paying for UK visa application in USA

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

Is there a way for me to check a biometrics appointment availability before paying for a UK visa application in the USA?
I have applied for a Schengen visa and depending on the approval/rejection of the visa, I plan to apply for a UK visa. However, I do not want to wait until after I get the Schengen visa to book an appointment if the appointment availability is far off. If availability is easy, I will wait it out.

Is there a way to determine appointment availability without paying for the application? I did not find this option in the gov.uk website.

Comment: Most biometric centers allow walk in. If you’re nicely dressed and have good articulation skills, you can swing it on slow days like Wednesday’s. You just tell them you have a crucial event on the your actual biometric appointment day which you have to attend.

Comment: Also, there are hundreds of ASCs all over the country. If the one nearest you doesn't have an appointment date soon enough for your taste, check another one.

Answer (score 4):

No. You have to apply online, pay the fee, then attend the appointment. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa Appointment slots only show in the online system after you’ve submitted the application. Once booked, it is possible to change an appointment.

It’s also possible to cancel an application and get the fee refunded, provided you do so before the appointment date.